# Print list from a dataframe based on another columns value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, lambda

I would like to **slice the dataframe according to conditions**. I want to keep the area name where the length of codes are 5 or 3.

The dataframe`AreaCode` is as bellowed

```
    codes   area
0   113     Leeds
2   115     Nottingham
3   116     Leicester
... ... ...
596 1985    Warminster
597 1986    Bungay
598 1987    Ebbsfleet
```

- This is the code I wrote, but it didn't work.

```
# print([AreaCode['codes']>4])
for i in AreaCode['codes']:
    if len(i)>4:
        print(AreaCode['area'][i])
```

Comment: What do you get with `print(df['codes'].dtype)`?

Comment: I got an Object, but I read the csv through pandas.read_csv()

Comment: `df[df['codes'].str.len() != 4]`

Comment: or `df[df['codes'].str.len().isin([3,5])]`.

Comment: Can I ask that does object impacts on this ?

Comment: you can only use `.str` accessor on string types. Your sample data looks like `codes` is of `int` type.

Comment: Thank you for this useful information!